# C#: How to copy only the differences in a file from one directory to another

Tags: c#, file-io, diff

Say I have a big file in one directory and an older version of it in another. Is it somehow possible to update the older version with only the changes in the new one? So that I would copy only a small fraction from one place to another. Would have to work for both text and binary files.

Not sure if this is possible though, but curious to if it is.

Comment: I don't think this is possible unless you are willing to write your own diff code. If not then there is also a CRC, which will return a value for both files, if these values are equal then the files are identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any gained from such thing because to see the difference between two files you must read the whole files and compare them. I don't think this will be faster than just copying them.

Comment: Yeah, that was kind of what I was wondering about as well. So I guess I will keep it simple =)

Comment: not necessarily true.
Saved bandwidth might be the deciding factor.

Answer (score 1):

Sure! There are plenty of diff implementations.

- http://www.mathertel.de/Diff/
- http://www.alexandre-gomes.com/?p=177

Just adapt them to your needs.

Comment: These seems to be for text files though?

Comment: doesn't matter. The algorithm works for any character sequences.

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is exactly what [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) is best at.  Use the tool best suited to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

May be a part of solution can be found with Sync Framework.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/default.aspx

A sample: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mail2sharad/FileSyncProvider01012008193150PM/FileSyncProvider.aspx

Hope this help.